# PHP/MYSQL counting the most ordered product

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, count

Users table:

[image]

Order_items table:

[image]

Orders table:

[image]

```
$sql[2] = "SELECT p.p_name, o.created, COUNT(oi.id) AS db FROM products AS p
           INNER JOIN order_items AS oi ON oi.product_id = p.id
           INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.id = oi.order_id
           GROUP BY p.p_name
           ORDER BY db DESC, o.created DESC
           LIMIT 1";

$result3= mysqli_query($conn,$sql[2]) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0)
{
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        echo $record['p_name']." - ".$record['db']." - ".$record['created']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

I want count the most ordered products name, and how manny product is sold, and the last date when this product is ordered. In this case the result looks like:
Barack - 4 - 2016-12-15 09:36:21 But my SELECT is counting only 3. Any ideas how can I fix ?

Comment: offtopic you are using GROUP BY wrong. o.created be every value because its not named in the GROUP BY statement.. And make a sql dump off your tables and post that here (or on sqlfiddle.com) instead off images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.p_name,
    MAX(o.created) AS created,
    COUNT(oi.id) AS db
FROM order_items AS oi
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON oi.order_id= o.id
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = oi.product_id 
GROUP BY oi.product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(oi.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

***Updated:***
Cause there is no `order_id = 3` in your table `Orders`, so `INNER JOIN` will give you 3, if you want to get 4, use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: same result, got 3 insead of 4

Comment: @FaragoRoland There is no `order_id = 3`  in your table `order`. If you want to get 4, then use `LEFT JOIN`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, now forking fine :)